# jassper-reports - csv formatting

Tags: csv, jasper-reports

I've got the following jasper file: 
This file should create a csv file and it also is. Though every 14th record is malformed (see csv under the jasper file). Has anyone got any idea why?

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="statisticsTBT" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6719b7f6-2c0e-4979-b55c-8db017b6df05">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="3.797498335832415"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
<field name="code" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="dateReception" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="dateInput" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="dateClosure" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="dateSigned" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="dateSignedDef" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="startBemiddeling" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="endBemiddeling" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="startRechtsgeding" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="endRechtsgeding" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="startHoofdbestuur" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="endHoofdbestuur" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="initialServiceDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="dossiersInTreatmentRecp" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="dossiersInTreatmentClose" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="dossierType" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="initialServiceCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="cadastralIncome" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="proposedCadastralIncome" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="cadastralIncomeDef" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="reasonInValidDef" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="fiscalYear" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="8bc70924-17fc-4371-bf24-bdcb5bd1a082"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="15" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="5a00c878-5a07-4556-ac59-ca93488d1c1a"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="33a84a35-106c-4843-9ade-628ebccc122f"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateReception}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="45" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="24e5e1fc-2a96-4c4e-8979-142912148617"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateInput}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="aa9dfe9e-705e-48ba-8bc5-78681421f0e2"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateClosure}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="75" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="50776a2e-ea89-469c-80f5-a09ed923edff"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateSigned}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="2784ebd9-380b-4ed9-9d84-6ca6b8d94b4c"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateSignedDef}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="105" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="033adaec-b48b-4f05-a62b-3b8624affc62"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{startBemiddeling}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="7ba5da83-fbe9-4cc3-90b5-cb09e8eab5e4"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{endBemiddeling}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="135" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="b78d39ea-ba72-44dd-8d8a-97d69f910489"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{startRechtsgeding}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="150" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="fc174497-43b4-40f6-b800-8d463f583416"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{endRechtsgeding}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

```
11: 727, null, 17/02/14 0:00, 17/02/14 0:00, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
12: 729, null, 17/02/14 0:00, 17/02/14 0:00, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
13: 730, null, 14/02/14 0:, 17/02/14 0:, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
14: , , 00, 00, , , , , , ,
```

notice how row 14 takes the 00 and 00 from row 13.. It's the exact same result on row 28, 42, ...

Comment: What is your datasource?

Comment: It's a JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource.

Comment: Can you post the test sample with data?

Comment: You're asking to copy past my database in here? Cause euhmm.. ^^